# How to retrieve object from database using LINQ expression from many-to-many join table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to retrieve all `players` from `db` for one `club` where they are in `M:M` relationship using `PlayerClubs` join table. My code is working but really doesn't want that approach for example, first I am retrieving all `players` from `db`

```
var players = await _context.PlayerClubs.Where(pc => pc.ClubId == id).Select(p => p.Player).ToListAsync();
```

then I retrieve the `club` based on `id` which I receive from `controller`

```
var club = await _context.Clubs.Where(z => z.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

and lastly populate `ClubViewModel` with this `data`

```
return new ClubViewModel()
{
 Players = players,
 Club = club,
};
```

Now I want to populate this new `ClubViewModel` with just one `db` call i.e. `one query` using `linq` expression.

Things that I have tried

```
var query = (from c in _context.Clubs
             join pc in _context.PlayerClubs on c.Id equals pc.ClubId
             join player in _context.Players on pc.PlayerId equals player.Id
             where c.Id == id
             select new ClubViewModel
             {
                Players = player,
                Club = c,
             }).ToListAsync();
```

but I got stuck.

`PlayerClubs table`

[image: PlayerClubs Table]

Club

```
 public class Club
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [EnumDataType(typeof(Gender))]
  public Gender GenderType { get; set; }
  public int SeasonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string YearOfEstablishment { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string YearOfEntryIntoLeague { get; set; }
  public string Note { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("League")]    
  public int LeagueId { get; set; } 
  public virtual League League { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<PlayerClub> PlayerClubs { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<CoachClub> CoachClubs { get; set; }
}
```

Player

```
public class Player
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime Birth { get; set; } 
        public int LicenseNumber { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public virtual List<string> Clubs { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Club> Klubovi { get; set; }
        public virtual List<string> ClubNames { get; set; }
        [StringLength(13, ErrorMessage = "Матичниот број не може да биде подолг од 13 цифри")]
        public string Embg { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<PlayerClub> PlayerClubs { get; set; }

        public Player()
        {
            Clubs = new List<string>();
            ClubNames = new List<string>();
            Klubovi = new List<Club>();
        }

    }
```

PlayerClub

```
public class PlayerClub
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Club")]
        public int ClubId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Player")]
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }

        public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }


    }
```

ClubViewModel

```
public class ClubViewModel : Club
    {
        public Club Club { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public ClubViewModel()
        {
            Players = new List<Player>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your model.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Which one?

Comment: Classes `Club`, `PlayerClub`, `Player` and `ClubViewModel`

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```cs
var query = 
      from c in _context.Clubs
      where c.Id == id
      select new ClubViewModel
      {
            Players = c.PlayerClubs.Select(pc => pc.Player).ToList(),
            Club = c,
      };

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```